# PHP contact form not sending all information

Tags: php, forms

Hey guys I am using the following script for a email contact form, when I test the form it is not including the 2 additional fields I added to the form (Phone and company) in the email I receive

Very new to PHP. Can anyone help me out? Cheers!

```
 <?php 
 $action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
 if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
{ 
?> <div class="input-group">
<form  action="#contact" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" > 
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control form-control1" />
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control form-control1" />
<input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control form-control1" />
<input name="company" type="text" placeholder="Company" class="form-control form-control1" />
<input name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject"  class="form-control form-control1"/>
<textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="12" placeholder="Let us know what you require"></textarea><br> 
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="quoteb" /> 
</form> 
</div>
<?php 
}  
 else                /* send the submitted data */ 
{ 
$name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
$email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
$message=$_REQUEST['phone']; 
$message=$_REQUEST['company']; 
$message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
$message=$_REQUEST['subject']; 
if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
    { 
    echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
    } 
else{         
    $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
    $subject="$subject"; 
    mail("sales@webxury.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
    echo "Email sent, we will contact you ASAP, thank you"; 
    } 
}   
 ?>
```

Comment: You are totally wrong with your code!

Comment: how? please help me I am so new with PHP

Comment: Look at the @abraCadaver s answer, he has notified some of the errors from your code! tnx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are redefining `$message` each time.  Try:

```
$message = $_REQUEST['phone']; 
$message .= $_REQUEST['company']; 
$message .= $_REQUEST['message']; 
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
```

And the last one should probably be `$subject`.

Comment: thank you very much, it is working now, but Phone, Company and Message are all being displayed on the same line in the email I receive, is there any way to put a line break after them ?

Comment: Add a newline `$_REQUEST['phone'] . "\n";`

Answer (score 1):

Each time you are reassigning the variable $message.
Instead of this you can use below syntax:

```
 
 $message =$_REQUEST['phone']; 
   
 $message .=$_REQUEST['company']; 
   
 $message .=$_REQUEST['message']; 
   
 $message .=$_REQUEST['subject'];
```

Answer (score 1):

For line break try following

```
$message  = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$message .="\n"; 
$message .= $_REQUEST['company']; 
$message .="\n";
$message .= $_REQUEST['message'];
```

As am a new user i don't have privilege to add comment to your new line query, so adding it here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the data that is missing is 'phone', 'country' and 'message'. You are replacing these with each assignment to `$message`. You need to look at [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).